# How does increments the integer in (all) loops work?

Tags: java

how does increment the integer in (all) loops work ?
Like in the first time it initialize the integer then it checks the condition then increments the value and after that it does what i told it to do or it initialize the integer then it checks the condition and it does what i told it to do then increment the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a for loop,

```
for (a;b;c){
   // code d
}
```

1) It runs statement a first.

2) Then checks statement b.

3a) If b fails it exits the loop.

3b) If it passes, it executes d ONCE.  If at any point in d does it exit (eg. break), it will not do anything else in the loop.  If it does not break and completes all the code in d, then it runs statement c once.

3) repeat steps 2, 3 until 3a is true.

Comment: is it the same in while and do while loops ?

Comment: while do/while loops are simpler.  They evaluate a single expression either at the beginning or end, and if it's false, it will exit.  However if you are counting iterations, you need to declare your own variable outside of the construct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a for loop:

```
for (<initialization>; <condition>; <increment>) {
    // loop body
}
```

The initialization is executed first. Then the condition is evaluated, and if it evaluates to `true`, the loop's body is executed. Once that's done, the increment is executed. Then, the condition is evaluated again, and the whole process repeats until the condition no longer evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

for-loop:

```
initialize->condition->code->increment->condition──false──>end
                         └───────true───────┘
```

while-loop:

```
condition->code->condition──false──>end
             └─true─┘
```

do-while-loop:

```
code->condition──false──>end
 └─true─┘
```

PS: If you downvote, do it at least for an objective reason. If I made a mistake please tell me.

Comment: why don't you increment in your while and do-while example ?

Comment: Normally you don't have a counter in (do-)while-loops, because you if you need a counter then you will use a for because it is already built-in. So your condition is something arbitrary that's embedded in your code-section. Therefore I didn't write the increment specifically.